# Do we have $K(\beta)=K(\beta^2)$ for field extension of odd degree?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $K\subseteq K(\beta)$ be a finite [field extension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_extension) of odd degree. Does this imply $K(\beta)=K(\beta^2)$?

Comment: Yes  $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$

Comment: Since $[K(\beta):K]$ is odd we have $[K(\beta):K]=2k+1$ for some $k\in\mathbb N^*.$ Or  $\beta^2\in K(\beta)$  implies that $K(\beta^2)\subset K(\beta)\Longrightarrow$  $[K(\beta):K(\beta^2)]|2k+1$ so $[K(\beta):K(\beta^2)]=1$ thus $K(\beta)=K(\beta^2).$

Answer (score 2):

The degree $[K(\beta):K(\beta^2)]$ divides $[K(\beta):K]$, but it can be only $1$ or $2$. Now conclude. :-)